# Combine jquery map scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two scripts for rendering maps via jquery.

One here:

```
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var loca = new google.maps.LatLng(41.7475, -74.0872);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: loca,
      zoom: 12
    });

  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        }

   function codeAddress() {
   var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    var request = {
      location: results[0].geometry.location,
      radius: 50000,
      name: 'ski',
      keyword: 'mountain',
      type: ['park']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

renders a Google map which asks users to enter their location and then pinpoints it on the map.

And the one here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude

var locations = [

  ['<h4><a href="#">My Home</a></h4>', 19.114282,72.871037]
,

  ['<h4><a href="#">My parents home</a></h4>', 18.9443219,72.8227124]


];


// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
  iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]
var icons_length = icons.length;


var shadow = {
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
  url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 2,

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
});

var marker;
var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon : icons[iconCounter],
    shadow: shadow
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  iconCounter++;
  // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
  if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function AutoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
AutoCenter();
 </script>
```

Renders a Google map with the two markers that I've defined to be pinpointed on the map.

My question is that how can I combine these two scripts to render the whole thing on a single map? Please help/guide me.

**Edit:** 
Adding this script to the bottom of the combined scripts I'm able to successfully detect the geolocation of the user automatically. But the map isn't getting centered on that point. Require help for this as well.

```
  // Check if user support geo-location
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: geolocpoint,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    // Place a marker
    var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: geolocpoint,
        map: map,
        title: 'Your geolocation',
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
    });
});
  }
```

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/fY7Bx/ and try to find where the issues are.

Comment: However, the error I'm trying to rectify here is how to centre the map on the user location. Right now only the marker is getting created but the map is not getting centred there.

Comment: Which marker? When you search for a place?

Comment: No, not that. It's working perfectly. I have added an edit to my question, please take a look at that.

Comment: Anyway, you have `geolocpoint`. Why don't use that to center the map on the location?

Comment: It's not centering using `geolocpoint` .Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fY7Bx/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the `geolocpoint` variable, except adding a marker. You need to use `map.setCenter(geolocpoint);` at some point to center the map on the user location.

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/fY7Bx/5/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out a while later, once I'm home. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if I replied to your question.

Comment: Yes, i'll do that. :)